# SQL Query to display the name, job, department name salary and grade

Tags: sql

The question is:

- "Create a query that will display the `NAME, JOB, DEPARTMENT NAME, SALARY` and `GRADE`(from the `SALGRADE` table) for all `EMPLOYEES`."

My code so far:

```
SELECT e.ename, e.job, d.dname, e.sal, s.grade
FROM emp e, dept d, salgrade s
WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno
```

This returns 70 rows, but the result should only produce **14** rows.

```
EMPLOYEE   EMP JOB   DEPT NAME      EMP SALARY SALARY GRADE                               
---------- --------- -------------- ---------- ------------                               
JAMES      CLERK     SALES                 950            1                               
SMITH      CLERK     RESEARCH              800            1                               
ADAMS      CLERK     RESEARCH             1100            1                               
MARTIN     SALESMAN  SALES                1250            2                               
WARD       SALESMAN  SALES                1250            2                               
MILLER     CLERK     ACCOUNTING           1300            2                               
ALLEN      SALESMAN  SALES                1600            3                               
TURNER     SALESMAN  SALES                1500            3                               
BLAKE      MANAGER   RESEARCH             2850            4                               
CLARK      MANAGER   ACCOUNTING           2450            4                               
JONES      MANAGER   RESEARCH             2975            4                               
FORD       ANALYST   RESEARCH             3000            4                               
SCOTT      ANALYST   RESEARCH             3000            4                               
KING       PRESIDENT ACCOUNTING           5000            5
```

- `emp` table has `empno, ename, job, deptno, comm, sal`
- `salgrade` table has `grade`
- `DEPT` table has `deptno, loc`

Comment: no need to use capital letters!

Comment: where missing link in the table salgrade?

Answer (score 3):

The root cause is your use of the old, deprecated "implicit join" syntax:

```
  select e.ename, e.job, d.dname, e.sal, s.grade
  from emp e, dept d, salgrade s
  where e.deptno = d.deptno
```

You're only joining the `emp` and `dept` table with a condition in the `WHERE` clause - your `salgrade` table is cross joined - one entry there will be matched against all entries from the result.

I would recommend to **always** use the new ANSI standard JOIN syntax:

```
  SELECT 
       e.ename, e.job, d.dname, e.sal, s.grade
  FROM 
       dbo.emp e
  INNER JOIN 
       dbo.dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno
  INNER JOIN 
       dbo.salgrade s ON ???????
```

Right away, you see there's **no condition** defined on how to join the `salgrade` table into your query - you need to provide an appropriate condition here, then your result should be just fine!

Comment: will the condition be  includes all employees? @marc_s

Comment: @rohit: I don't understand what you're asking - sorry. There needs to be some kind of a link between `emp` and `salgrade` (most likely) - somehow, you must know what salary grade each employee is - right?? That's the missing condition that needs to be put there: `INNER JOIN dbo.salgrade s ON e.salgradeid = s.grade` or whatever those columns are called.....

Answer (score 2):

CREATE A QUERY THAT WILL DISPLAY THE NAME,JOB,DEPARTMENT NAME,SALARY AND GRADE( FROM THE SALGRADE TABLE) FOR ALL EMPLOYEES
query should be ---

```
SELECT e.ename,e.job,dname,e.sal,g.grade 
FROM emp e,dept,salgrade g 
WHERE (e.sal BETWEEN g.losal AND g.hisal) AND e.deptno=dept.deptno;
```

Comment: only correct answer from given above. great work man keep it up

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
SELECT e.ename,e.job,d.dname,e.sal,s.grade
  FROM emp e , dept d ,salgrade s
 WHERE e.deptno=d.deptno
 GROUP BY e.ename
```

Comment: still giving me 70 rows instead of 14 @Bryan

Answer (score 1):

```
 select e.ename, e.job, d.dname, e.sal, s.grade
   from emp e, dept d, salgrade s
  where e.deptno = d.deptno
    and s.grade in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: still gives me 70 rows @ Sam Casil

Answer (score -1):

try this one while using join

```
select e.ename,d.dname,s.grade 
from emp e 
join dept d on (e.deptno=d.deptno)
join salgrade s on (e.sal between s.losal and s.hisal);
```